# How can I extend mat-select component in Material Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, dom-events, event-bubbling, angular8

I would like to create my own select component by extending Angular material component `mat-select` and use my custom `app-select` component like below

```
<app-select>
  <mat-option>Value1</mat-option>
  <mat-option>Value2</mat-option>
  <mat-option>Value3</mat-option>
  <mat-option>Value4</mat-option>
</app-select>
```

I have made an example in stackblitz where I almost got it to work. **The issue** Im having is that the dropdown panel wont close after selecting an option.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdyjcy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect%2Fselect.component.html

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.css']
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option>
      None
    </mat-option>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: don't wont to cause any doubts but you also lost some focus and keyboard related functionality

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the technicalities of your question, but there is another way to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

pass the options as an array like this

```
class ParentComponent {
  public options = [
    'Value1',
    'Value2',
    'Value3',
    'Value4',
    'Value5'
  ];
}
```

```
<app-select [options]="options">
</app-select>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.css']
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() options: string[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option>
      None
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options">{{ option }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extend MatSelect

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [{ provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: EfilingSelect }]
})

export class SelectComponent extends MatSelect {
...
}

MatSelect will implement OnInit

You might need to add a provider if you're going to use the component in a mat-form-field element